# how to add image/css file source in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Can anyone please explain the steps to follow insert an image in shiny app.do we need to set working directory to the app location and I have also created www folder insider app folder, but still I am unable to load the logo or CSS file in the shiny app..it would be of great help if anyone could help me get through this

Comment: You need to give the full path.  The working directory for shiny is deep in the shiny package folder of your R library not the directory where your app is located.

Comment: Could you please share the path for it because i couldn't trace the path correctly

Comment: Put  print(getwd()) into the server code and it should show in your console.

Comment: Do you not know how to get the full path to your folder with the shiny code?

Comment: When you get it working please be sure to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full path. The working directory for shiny is deep in the shiny package folder of your R library not the directory where your app is located.